# Le point exclarrogatif

Tags: orthographe, ponctuation

Ce point permet de ponctuer une phrase exclamative et interrogative à la fois sans prédominance. Néanmoins je ne l'ai jamais vu utilisé et j'ai du mal à me représenter une phrase qui soit impossible à départager. Dans quel type de phrase est-il utile de le placer et quel en est le but ? Car on pourrait utiliser "!?" simplement.

**EDIT**

Le point exclarrogatif (‽) n'est pas le point d'exclamation (!) suivit/précédé du point d'interrogation (?), qui insiste soit sur le questionnement soit sur l'exclamation en fonction de leur position. Il s'agit bel et bien d'un signe de ponctuation à part entière. Et son utilisation est plus que rare et difficile. D'où mon interrogation sur son utilité et le but de son existence.

Comment: Je sais pas si ca fonctionne: Chéri, je suis enceinte.

Tu es enceinte !?

Comment: c'est plus une question de rhétorique comme "Comment veux-tu que je le sache ?!".

Comment: J'ai tendance à l'écrire dans cet ordre plutôt : `?!` Car je l'emploie vraiment comme une question avec une intonation exclamative. Et c'est en général pour retranscrire à l'écrit quelque chose d'oral. Comme par exemple : `Qu'est-ce que tu dis ?!`

Comment: Trouvé les caractères spéciaux sous 'Ponctuation générale', selon les polices : Linux Libertine : `⁇ ⁈ ⁉` pas de !! qui est le seul caractère de ponctuation spéciale pour Arial et Garamond : `‼` ;

Comment: Il est disponible en tapant le code HTML : "&#8253;" et sous Windows, si le navigateur le permet, on peut également l'afficher avec la combinaison "alt" enfoncée + "8253".

Answer (score 3):

Il existe une nuance entre ?! et !?.

Le !? peut être utilisé pour une question rhétorique tandis que le ?! est utilisé pour un réel questionnement.

Aux échecs on les utilise tout deux en tant que commentaires lors d'une partie:

> !     Bon coup
>
> !!    Très bon coup
>
> ?     Mauvais coup
>
> ??    Très mauvais coup
>
> !?    Coup intéressant, peut-être bon
>
> ?!    Coup douteux

Answer (score 1):

Je l'écrirais aussi dans l'autre sens "?!"
Je l'utilise souvent pour montrer une surprise.

Les exemples développés dans les commentaires sont très bien.